# В чем проблема, хотел написать код для статуса бота, а он выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: discord

```
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream"))
```

Пишет:

> File "bot/bot.py", line 7
>       await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream"))
>       ^ SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Comment: Так у вас же в ошибке написанно: await вне функции. Т.е вам нужно создать функцию и к ней уже применять await.